# UK Visitor Visa - Financial Dependents

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

My brother-in-law and my sister are planning to visit the UK for a holiday. They both are full-time employees and on their day-to-day work my sister doesn't depend on my brother-in-law financially. But for the trip, only my brother-in-law shows his savings account as a proof of funding for both of them. Because of this reason should he include my sister in the following question?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your sister not have bank accounts of her own?

Comment: No She doesn’t. They put money into one account for savings purposes.

Comment: Is this savings account in both their names or just in his?

Comment: It's just under his name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write "my sister doesn't depend on my brother-in-law financially". But you also write that all the money she earns goes into an account in his sole name. At that point the money becomes his, in the sense that if he decided not to let her take it, she could not. Therefore your sister is in fact financially dependent on your brother-in-law. Your brother-in-law may well give your sister any money she asks for, but visa agents have no way of being sure that is true.

You should therefore definitely say that your sister is a dependent on your brother-in-law. It's absolutely normal that spouses are considered dependents of their spouses, even if they maintain their own bank accounts. She should also answer the question about who is paying for the trip by saying that her husband is paying.

Comment: Thanks, @DJClayworth for your answer. They paid for the visa 4 days ago and had scheduled their appointment for this Monday. But we cancelled it due to this error. But I wanted to double check, thanks. I've applied for my wife's parent's visa in 2016, but the application is so different and now they don't have to take a printed version of the application along with them to the appointment.